# How to remove array wrap for associated model in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs

Can you help me how I can replace value array of objects to just object

I have this query

```
await this.userRepository.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Role,
      as: 'role',
      through: {attributes: []},
    }
  ],
}
```

But I got this:

```
"role": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Admin"
    }
  ]
```

How can i get something like this?

```
"role": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Admin"
  }
```

Comment: try with `findOne`

Comment: @paranoid will be the same result. Field "role" it's one of the fields of user object.

Comment: As I can see you have M:N relationship between users and roles. so there is no guarantee you will have one role only for each user to be able to represent it with an object instead of an array. You either need to turn it to 1:1 or N:1 to be able to get a role as an object.